# NGINX showing 404 if there is '/' sign in last of URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Sorry! I tried to search for the answer on Google and Stackoverflow. But can't find it.

I am using NGINX and the URL I'm trying to access is `https://www.mywebsite.com/newsfeed.rss/`

The above URL shows 404, But if I acces the same URL without `/` in the last of URL, Then It works.
`https://www.mywebsite.com/newsfeed.rss`

So how I can display content on both URLS?

Comment: finishing with / is trying to access a folder, maybe you could set up some rule to check for files even when the request is a folder (even though I don't think it's a good idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;` returns a permanent redirect with the 301 code.

I prefer the following configuration

```
location /newsfeed.rss/ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 last;
}

location /newsfeed.rss {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Will it redirect the main URL? Or will it work for both URL's? (with and without '/')
I want to display content for both URL's

Comment: It works for both kinds of URL. I don't understand what `redirect the main URL` means, but this configuration doesn't lead to any redirect traffic

Answer (score 0):

in your nginx configuration you could rewite url's to a standard format by adding or removing trailing spaces.  It is better to add the slash because removing it can cause a redirect loop on browsers that adds the slash.

To add

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: It will effect all the URL's right? Can I do this for just one URL I mentioned in my question.

Comment: But that standardises your url it doesn't solve the problem of the trailing slash url not resolving to a resource.  You need to show the config you are using to understand that.